# Trying to create a simple ng-href page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a very simple `ng-href` page in AngularJS but it is not working and I cannot understand why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="href">

<head>
  <title>ngHref</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ngh">
  <div>
    <p>Go to<a ng-href="{{base}}">{{base}}</a></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var a = angular.module('href', [])
    a.controller('ngh', function() {

      this.base = 'www.google.com';
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `$scope.base = "https://google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$scope` to bind something to DOM. If you want use something with `this`. you should do something like:

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="ngh as vm">
```

JS

```
   var a = angular.module('href', [])
      a.controller('ngh', function() {

      var vm = this;

      vm.base = 'www.google.com'; // or this.base
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="href">

<head>
  <title>ngHref</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ngh">
  <div>
    <p>Go to<a ng-href="{{base}}">{{base}}</a></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var a = angular.module('href', [])
    a.controller('ngh', function($scope) {

      $scope.base = 'www.google.com';
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not working `code`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="href">
<head>
 <title>ngHref</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ngh as b">
 <div>
  <p>Go to<a ng-href="{{base}}">{{base}}</a></p>
 </div>
 <script>
  var a=angular.module('href', [])
  a.controller('ngh',function(){
   var b=this;
   b.base='http://www.google.com';
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>`code`

Comment: ok got it. Contrary to using $scope where the binded data is used directly, 'controller as' directive demands the alias alongwith variable too. So, instead of <a ng-href="{{base}}">Google</a></p>  it would be <a ng-href="{{b.base}}">Google</a></p>      Thanks anyways.